# python setup.py configuration to install files in custom directories

Tags: python, configuration, installation, setup.py

I want to create a setup.py which would install my files into custom directories. I have a certain prefix, where I would like to get the following result:

```
/my/prefix/
  bin/
    script.sh
  libexec/
    one.py
    two.py
    ...
  lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/
    package/...
```

My initial project is following:

```
/
  script.sh
  one.py
  two.py
  ...
  setup.py
  package/...
    __init__.py
    ...
```

What would be the best way to achieve that? I would like to be able to install it later with something like:

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/my/prefix
```

I can get "package" nicely installed in the correct directory as `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` under `--prefix` is the default location. But is there a clean way to get `script.sh` into "bin" and other python files into "libexec"? The only way I see to achieve that would be to manually copy those files in my `setup.py` script. Maybe there is a cleaner and more standard way to do that?

Comment: There's some useful docs on this here: https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation-unix-the-prefix-scheme and here https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/introduction.html

Comment: With `setuptools` see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24745852/520567

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scripts are handled by use of the `scripts` parameter to the setup function. For libexec you can treat them as data files and use a data options.

```
setup(...
    scripts=glob("bin/*"),
    data_files=[(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'libexec', 'mypackage'), glob("libexec/*"))],
    ...
)
```

I'm not sure how that would work with a `--prefix` option, I've never tried that.

Comment: Thanks! data_files did it for me. Another question, can I have a default "prefix"? If the user doesn't specify one, I would like to use my own (instead of the python default).

Comment: You can make option defaults in the setup.cfg file. It's in .ini style option file with sections and name-value pairs. Command line options directly translate to options there (remove `--`, etc).

Comment: What's the best way to refer to `libexec` inside some of the files in the Python package if you are going to use `libexec` here in the `setup.py`? Can `setup.py` do macro substitution in the same vein as autoconf `@libexecdir@`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with `setup.py` like that:

```
setup(name='mylib',
  scripts=['script.sh'],
  data_files=[('libexec', ['one.py', 'two.py'])]
)
```

Of course, you could iterate over all python files for libexec, but I only have 2-3 python files I need there.

---

Additionally, I can have `setup.cfg` with the following:

```
[install]
prefix=/my/prefix
```

and instead of `python setup.py install --prefix=/my/prefix` I can just do:

```
python setup.py install
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as edits ([edit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10458158/2), [edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10458158/3)) to the question [python setup.py configuration to install files in custom directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458158/python-setup-py-configuration-to-install-files-in-custom-directories) by the OP [Ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122128/ago) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>