# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Project when using sys.path.append()

Tags: python

I'm trying to import models from a folder in the parent directory. Im using sys.path.append(). My project structure:

-Project

- folder1

  - file1.py
  - ...
- folder2

  - file2.py
  - ...

In file1.py file:

```
sys.path.append('../Project')
from Project.folder2 import file2
```

I then get a:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Project
```

I know there are other ways but this seems like the simplest. I'm not sure if I need to put the absolute path to the Project folder, but I'm hoping not since I'll be running this Project on different computers (diff abs path).

Comment: do  you have a ```__init__.py``` file in your Project directory?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `sys.path.append('..')`, since you're using `from Project....`?

Comment: @ewong I do not. I read somewhere that __init__ files are no longer needed with python3, but whats your thoughts?

Comment: @joanis whats the exact append statement? ".." isnt valid

Comment: I would have expected `sys.path.append('..')` to add the parent directory of your current working directory. But maybe Python doesn't allow that? Anyway, my point is that if `xyz/Project` is on sys.path, Python would look for module `Project` in `xyz/Project/Project/` instead of directly in `xyz/Project/`.

Comment: I just tested `sys.path.append('..')` with a simpler setup, and it worked for me.

Comment: I just read Niel's answer, and this is a bad idea anyway, because the path is going to be relative the where your process is running, not relative to where your file is located.

Comment: The way I work with things like this is to actually do an in-place pip install: create a `setup.py` and run `pip install -e .` at the root of your project, so that it's actually installed and visible to Python from anywhere.

Comment: @joanis interesting! i went with niels way of just adding the abs path. with your way, is setup.py like a requirements.txt file? and you just put all the apps you want in there?

Comment: The setup.py file can have the contents of the requiments.txt file, or in my case, read the requirements.txt file. But it contains everything else needed for `pip install -e .` to know what to do. And it will be required if you publish your project to PyPI at some point. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4740473/3216427 for some examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 errors in your code:

1. The `Project` directory is not just 1-level up. From the point of view of `file1.py`, it is actually 2 levels up. See this:

```
$ cd ..
(venv) nponcian 1$ tree
.
└── Project
    ├── folder1
    │   └── file1.py
    └── folder2
        └── file2.py
(venv) nponcian 1$ cd Project/folder1/
(venv) nponcian folder1$ ls ..
folder1  folder2
(venv) nponcian folder1$ ls ../..
Project
```

2. Even if the above works, adding a relative path as a string would literally append that string as its raw value. So if you add a `print(sys.path)`, it would display something like this:

```
['/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '../Project', '.']
```

- It literally added `'../Project'`, so if python started [searching for the target modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in folder2, it wouldn't still find them because how would it know where exactly is `'../Project'` relative to.

#### Solution

What you need to add is the absolute path. If your problem is it might change, it is fine because we don't need a fixed absolute path. We can get the absolute path through the location of the current file being executed e.g. `file1.py` and then extracting the parent directory needed. Thus, this will work regardless if the absolute paths change because the way we are getting it is always relative to `file1.py`. Try this:

**Project/folder1/file1.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent))  # 1. <.parent> contains this file1.py 2. <.parent.parent> contains folder1 3. <.parent.parent.parent> contains Project

... the rest of the file
```

Comment: this makes sense and is a great solution to my problem. it's still not working unfortunately but I feel close. when I print out my path after adding your suggestion above, my path is still /Users/chad.lei/Downloads/Project1/folder1. what I should be seeing is /Users/chad.lei/Downloads/ right? Also, when I print out Path(__file__).parent I get a '.' returned.

Comment: i also tried using resolve on Path(__file__) first. still getting . for some reason

Comment: Just like how you originally planned with doing `../../..<etc.>`, you just have to keep on chaining `.parent.parent.parent.<etc.>` until you reach the target parent directory relative to the executed file. I hope you already resolved it :)

Comment: Hey, that's a really cool tool, `tree`!

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano can you help with another similar issue? I have a file (File A) in the parent directory that imports File B from a folder in the same directory as A. File B imports a file (File C) from the same directory it's in. If I run File B directly, it runs fine. But If I run File A, File B gives me a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'File C'. What can I do here?

Comment: @chadlei Perhaps you performed an implicit relative import when you imported C into B that's why it didn't work when you changed your current path to the outer directory. If ever it is indeed implicit relative import, try changing it to explicit `from .C import something` (notice the `.` in the beginning of `C`). Of course it could also be absolute path `from parentx.parenty.C import something`

Comment: I'll give that a try thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

You can solve this by creating a `setup.py` file for your project and then running `pip install -e .`, instead of modifying `sys.path`.

**Motivation**

This answer might seem to come from left field for this question, but I'm putting it here because OP showed interest in this solution, and I think it's generally a preferable solution to mucking around with `sys.path`.

**Details**

The solution I tend to prefer for my projects is to create an actual setup.py for them, as if I was going to publish them to PyPI, and then run `pip install -e .` to have them actually installed in my (possibly virtual) python environment.

Here's a minimalist `setup.py` similar to one I used before:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="project",
    version="0.0.1",
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    author="Some cool dude",
    long_description="Some cool project",
    install_requires=["dep1", "dep2"],
)
```

In another project, I read my `requirements.txt` file in my `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup

with open("requirements.txt") as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name="project",
    version="0.0.1",
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    author="Some cool dude",
    long_description="Some cool project",
    install_requires=requirements,
)
```

With either solution, the `setup.py` file is sibling to my `project` directory (I use lowercase for my project names, always), both typically being at the root of my Git repo, or under a `src` subdirectory.

cd to the directory where `setyp.py` and `project` are, and run

```
pip install -e .
```

and now from anywhere, you can `import project` or its submodules and Python will find them.

**Suggested reading**

Lots more details can be found about `setup.py` files at [setup.py examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4740473/3216427)

Comment: can you help with another similar issue? I have a file (File A) in the parent directory that imports File B from a folder in the same directory as A. File B imports a file (File C) from the same directory it's in. If I run File B directly, it runs fine. But If I run File A, File B gives me a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'File C'. What can I do here? @joanis

Comment: This might be worth asking as its own question, with a pointer to this one for context. But, let me try to understand first... A, B, and C are in the parent dir of Project? So, they're not in a dir your python path, right? Are they in the directory where you are running?

Comment: A and Folder Z that contains B and C are in the parent directory. I'm running A which is in the parent directory. They are not in my python path

Comment: Generally, I use import statements that fully qualify where to import from, all the time. So if Z.B imports Z.C, I say `import Z.C` even in Z.B, rather than rely on any kind of localness of the files.

Comment: If `import Z.B` worked in A, then I would expect `import Z.C` to work in Z.B in that same execution environment.

Comment: oh ok specifying the file within B worked! thanks again

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue in Windows OS. In addition to possible level injection as a parent, the problem with sys.path.append is that it creates a windows path which Python is not searching for some reason despite it being added to the sys.path. Instead try to use

`ROOT_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[1]`

```
 sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, ''))
```

It will add file's grandparent to sys.path in a proper way.