# python unittest file fails to import from other directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

That is my project/source directory. I am using unittest and trying to run these tests from bash: 'python -m unittest'. I have tried many different things from using os and adding it to syspath and different similar approaches, also tried many different options of importing itself like 'from algorithms import BubbleSort', or 'from algorithms.BubbleSort import BubbleSort'. Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure?rq=1) for example but it didn't help either.

[image]

```
# inside MergeSort file
class MergeSort:
    def sort_asc(self, list):
        return sorted_list

# inside BubbleSort file
class BubbleSort:
    def sort_asc(self, list):
        return sorted_list

# inside test_main
import unittest

from algorithms.MergeSort import MergeSort
from algorithms.BubbleSort import BubbleSort
from utility.Utils import Utils


class test_algorithms(unittest.TestCase):
    # and here are all my test functions
    def test_bubble_asc_empty(self):
        numbers = []
        self.assertListEqual(BubbleSort().sort_asc(numbers), [])
```

Files BubbleSort and MergeSort both contain 1 class called same as the filename. Inside the application view files from eg. controllers directory can normally access algorithms directory files by importing algorithms.BubbleSort but this test_main.py just can't do same thing for some reason and all my attempts end up having either this 'is not defined error', 'module object is not callable error' or 'failed to import module error'. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: @ReblochonMasque it changes my error to TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can see what's happening.

Comment: If you use `import algorithms.BubbleSort` then you should reference the class with `BubbleSort.BubbleSort` (`module_name.class_name`).

Comment: @tlgs i added some shape of the code i have in my files.

Comment: I realised now that if I call my tests using python -m tests.test_main they don't have any problems with importing but if i call python -m unittest (like internet told me to) it has these problems with importing (pycharm also won't run it)

Comment: Is your module pip-installed? When I do something like this, I work with an editable install, via `pip install -e .` run where the top-level `setup.py` is, so that Python sees my module from anywhere.

Comment: Do you still have the `__init__.py` files under both `algorithms` and `tests`?

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228512/3216427